# Azure Site-to-Site network bypassing VPN tunnel

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have a couple of queries about Azure VNet to On-Premises Site-to-Site networking -

1. As per Azure, Site-to-Site connection between On-Premises and Azure VNet should have a VPN tunnel. For this to happen there should be a VPN supported device at On-Prem and also a VPN Gateway at VNet. Is my understanding correct ?
2. Secondly, if a custom device capable of VPN functionality is deployed at On-Prem as well as a VM in Azure VNet, can they establish a connection between them without default Azure provided Site-to-Site VPN tunnel ? Is it possible to establish a network in Site-to-Site without VPN tunnel like with just igw's(Internet Gateways in AWS Cloud)?
3. What is the significance of next hop being "Internet" in azure route table ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. This device should also have a real external ip address, not behind the NAT.
2. Yes, you could use, say, Sophos to create VPN without using Azure's default VPN.
3. Internet. Represents the default Internet gateway provided by the Azure Infrastructure. (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-udr-overview/)